# Regex to separate nationality from text

Tags: c#, regex

I have list of Nationalities of people against their entries, most of entries are properly given, but some of the entries are given as below;
Proper ones are like below;

```
German
Iranian
Qatar
```

Improper are like below;

> Possibly **Ethiopian**

- *(text before nationality)*

> **Lebanon** citizenship

- *(text after nationality)*

> **DRC** and **Belgian** nationalities

- *(nationalities joined with and)*

> (1) **Germany** (b) **Algeria**

- *(with 1 and b as separator)*

> (a) **Russian**  (b) **Georgia**

- *(with a and b separator)*

> a) **French**, b) **Tunisian**

- *( with a and , and b separator)*

> **Indonesian** (as at December 2003)

- *(a different text after nationality)*

> **Iranian** (Iranian citizenship)

- *(another text after nationality)*

> **Sudanese** by birth

- *(another text after nationality)*

> (1) **Russian** (2) **USSR** (until 1991)

- *(text after 2nd entry)*

> **Bahrain** (citizenship revoked in January 2015)

- *(different text again)*

> **United States of America**. Also believed to hold **Syrian** nationality

- *(descriptive text containing nationality)*

> **Tunisian** (dual nationality)

- *(different text)*

> (1) **German** (2) **Moroccan**

- *( 1 and 2 with () double parentheses)*

> 1) **Saudi Arabia** 2) **Qatar**

- *(1 and 2 with ) parentheses)*

> a) **Central African Republic** b) **South Sudan**

- *(with single parentheses)*

> **Iranian** national and **US** national/citizen

- *(nationality inside text and joined with and)*

> **Kuwaiti** citizenship withdrawn in 2002

- *(a different text)*

I need to take out only bold text (Nationalities) from given text. Nationality can be of any country, these are just samples of some countries.

How would I apply regex or any type conditions which give results as expected. 
I have tried to check if text contains such characters then split them. for which I need to create more that 20 conditions  and which also not good approach to do this.

```
List<string> listOfNationalities = listOfNationalities;

List<string> multiple new List<string>();
foreach (var nationality in listOfNationalities)
{
    if(nationality.Contains("(1)"))
    {
        string[] nat = nationality.Split(')'); 
        foreach (var item in nat)
        {
            multiple.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on the amount of text(s) to be parsed, the frequency, and the performance requirements,  having multiple regular expressions might be a very good solution because it will be easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Have you a already a regex (because I don't think you need one if you a a List of nationalities)

Comment: @charlesLgn no I don't have any regex

Comment: Why you think you need to use Regex? If you have your nationalities list, just check if your string contains one of the nationalities from "NationalitiesList" or not.

Comment: @SeM I think regex would limit the code to short

Comment: @trighati in this case, it will not.

Comment: Do you have a list of all the valid nationalities ?

Comment: @Spotted yes I have.

Answer (score 2):

If the nationalities is provided by a fixed list of available options.
You can do the following:

```
List<string> listOfNationalities = listOfNationalities;

List<string> validNationalities = new List<string>();
validNationalities.Add("Brazilian");
validNationalities.Add("Japanese");
validNationalities.Add("...");

List<string> multiple = listOfNationalities.Where(n => validNationalities.Contains(n));
```

or even simpler:

```
string listOfNationalities = string.Join("|",listOfNationalities);

List<string> validNationalities = new List<string>();
validNationalities.Add("Brazilian");
validNationalities.Add("Japanese");
validNationalities.Add("...");

List<string> multiple = validNationalities.Where(n => listOfNationalities.Contains(n));
```

In this way, you will get the two nationalities given.

Comment: This doesn't ensure that the matched string is a whole word.

Comment: Some time nationality is Brazil and some times Brazilian, As I have written Qatar as Qatar .

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a list of valid nationalities, and *if the nationalities don't include special characters*, you can use something like the following to create the regex pattern at runtime:

```
public string NationalitiesPattern;

public string GetNationalitiesPattern()
{
    List<string> listOfNationalities = // All valid nationalities.
    string joinedNationalities = string.Join("|", listOfNationalities);
    return $@"\b(?:{joinedNationalities})\b";       // "\b(?:German|Iranian|Qatar|etc)\b"
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NationalitiesPattern))
    NationalitiesPattern = GetNationalitiesPattern();

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(inputString, NationalitiesPattern);
foreach (Match m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```